# iOS 7 device renders tableView a black color

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Currently, Im testing my app on two phones, one that runs iOS 8, and the other runs iOS 7. Recently, the iOS 7 device has started to render the view for the tableView entirely black when the code to update the view is called on it. Here is a screenshot of the how it looks. 
[image]

For comparison, here is how the iOS 8 view looks like. Im trying to determine what is causing the tableViewController to render the view entirely black. 
[image]

Here is my code to update the view. The reload method is called for an NSNotificationCenter notification posting.

```
-(void)setUpdatasource{
    self.chats = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.chats addObjectsFromArray:[[CDHandler sharedManager] fetchAllChats]];

}

-(void)reload{
    [self setUpdatasource];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
   // [self.tableView reloadInputViews];
}
```

Comment: My guess is that it's not rendering at all (the view is nil), so you're just seeing the window's black background. You can test this by changing the color of the window's background, and see if you get that new color.

Comment: I went ahead and changed the window color to whitecolor to see if the color would change. It didn't change the color.

Comment: Ok, you need to post the code you're using to update the view.

Comment: updated original question.

Comment: Have you logged self.chats to see if it contains anything? Does fetchAllChats operate on a background queue? Is that method asynchronous?

Comment: You said "Recently, the iOS 7 device has started..."  Does that mean that it used to render the table correctly?  Or has the iOS 7 device always had this problem?  If it has changed, what were you working on around the time it stopped working?

Comment: @rdelmar Chats does contain the actually messages. The fetchAllChats calls a query to the core data model and is currently not a asynchronous. @Nerrolken This was not an issue for the iOS 7 device and infact the view that you see within the iOS 8 phone was originally tested entirly with the iOS 7 phone. What Changed was in ViewDiDAppear I added ``[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO]``. Removing that line doesn't fix the problem. The reload method is called from an NSNotificationCenter posted notification.

Comment: were you ever able to fix this problem? I'm gaving the exact problem and can't seem to find the solution anywhere.

Comment: I haven't, I think the issue has to do with how views are rendered, There is a lot of changes in that domain between iOS 7 and 8, I've found a lot more graphical issues as well in iOS 8 using iOS 7 code.